# I can't put my numbers on a table to be displayed in a scientific format with precision of 4 numbers

Tags: overleaf, pgfplotstable

I am trying to make a data table with a data set and change my numbers display style.

I have this data set

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tabel_1.dat}
I[$A$]  B[$T$]
0       0
2       0.00795
2.8     0.01136
3.8     0.01521
4.6     0.01828
5.5     0.02221
5.9     0.02331
6.9     0.02730
7.9     0.03156
8.9     0.03555
\end{filecontents*}
```

And make the table with this code

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/index/.style={%
    create col/assign/.code={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\entry{\pgfplotstablerow+1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}
    }
    }
    }
\pgfplotstabletranspose\loadedtable{tabel_1.dat} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % expand the cells
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={%
                        before row={\hline%
                        \multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Tabel 1}
                        \\ },
                        output empty row},
after row={\hline},
every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},
every column/.style={column type/.add={|}{}},
string type,
]{\loadedtable}
```

I already tried `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci precision}` and its different forms, `every column/.style={precision=4, column type/.add={|}{}}` and nothing works.
I don't get any error messages but it doesn't change the way the numbers are displayed.

I use these packages

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
```

Comment: Why don't  you do that with `siunitx`, using the setting `\sisetup{exponent-mode=scientific }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what exactly you mean, but I think that's what you want:

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{table_1.dat}
I[$A$]  B[$T$]
0       0
2       0.00795
2.8     0.01136
3.8     0.01521
4.6     0.01828
5.5     0.02221
5.9     0.02331
6.9     0.02730
7.9     0.03156
8.9     0.03555
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        sci zerofill,
        sci precision=4,
        every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
        every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
        every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},
        every column/.style={column type/.add={|}{}}]
    {table_1.dat}
\end{document}
```

If you want all numbers to be displayed scientific with four digits just add a comma between `sci` and `zerofill`.

### Edit

An easy way to transpose a table is `\pgfplotstabletranspose`. This creates a new table and adds a new first row with numbers. If you want to typeset this new table you have to suppress this new row with `every head row/.style={output empty row}`. Also keep in mind that the old headers are no longer headers (now first column). So you have to add `every first column/.style={string type}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{table_1.dat}
I[$A$]  B[$T$]
0       0
2       0.00795
2.8     0.01136
3.8     0.01521
4.6     0.01828
5.5     0.02221
5.9     0.02331
6.9     0.02730
7.9     0.03156
8.9     0.03555
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[header=false]\tableTrans{table_1.dat}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        sci zerofill,
        sci precision=4,
        every first column/.style={string type},
        every head row/.style={output empty row, after row=\hline},
        every last row/.style={before row=\hline, after row=\hline},
        every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},
        every column/.style={column type/.add={|}{}}]
    {\tableTrans}
\end{document}
```

[image: transposed table]

Comment: That is what I want but I also need the table to be horizontal

Comment: I've edited my answer.